# How to preserve base data frame rownames upon filtering in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
df <- structure(list(BoneMarrow = c(30, 0, 0, 31138, 2703), Pulmonary = c(3380, 
21223.3333333333, 0, 0, 27)), row.names = c("ATP1B1", "CYCS", 
"DDX5", "GNB2L1", "PRR11"), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("BoneMarrow", 
"Pulmonary"))

df 
#>        BoneMarrow Pulmonary
#> ATP1B1         30   3380.00
#> CYCS            0  21223.33
#> DDX5            0      0.00
#> GNB2L1      31138      0.00
#> PRR11        2703     27.00
```

What I want to do is to get rid of rows with values < 8 in any of the columns. I tried this but the row names (e.g. ATP1B1, CYCS etc) are gone:

```r
> df %>% filter(!apply(., 1, function(row) any(row <= 8 )))
  BoneMarrow Pulmonary
1         30      3380
2       2703        27
```

How can I preserve that in dplyr chain?

Comment: The newer version of dplyr keeps the rows' names, so this not an issue anymore

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can convert rownames to a column and revert back after filtering:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)  # for `rownames_to_column` and `column_to_rownames`

df %>%
    rownames_to_column('gene') %>%
    filter_if(is.numeric, all_vars(. >= 8)) %>%
    column_to_rownames('gene')

#        BoneMarrow Pulmonary
# ATP1B1         30      3380
# PRR11        2703        27
```

Comment: This answer works great - but I keep wondering why dplyr is cutting the rownames in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

How about try this by using base R Boolean

```
df[rowSums(df>8)==dim(df)[2],] 

       BoneMarrow Pulmonary
ATP1B1         30      3380
PRR11        2703        27
```

EDIT1: Or you can do `df[!rowSums(df<8),]` (as per @user20650) will give back you same result.

Comment: nice and succinct answer. Would `df[!rowSums(df<8),]` also do it

Comment: @user20650 your answer is better ~

Comment: @YOBEN_S but your solution looks like base `R`, rather than `dplyr` (but you wrote "dplyr can definitely solve this problem...", so I'm curious).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another `base R` method with `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `>=`, 8)),]
#       BoneMarrow Pulmonary
#ATP1B1         30      3380
#PRR11        2703        27
```

Answer (score 2):

For gene counts, you often want to know if at least x samples have more than y counts, rather than just across all samples.

Not as pretty as filter_if, but I'm not sure how you'd implement the same rowSums conditions using all_vars

```
   x <- sample_threshold  
   y <- count_threshold

   require(dplyr) 
   require(tibble)

   df %>%  
       tibble::rownames_to_column('gene') %>%  
       dplyr::filter(rowSums(dplyr::select(., -gene) > y) > x) %>%  
       tibble::column_to_rownames('gene')
```

Answer (score 1):

As of `dplyr` 1.0.4 this is not an issue and they have introduced [`if_any`/`if_all`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/) to make this task much easier:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ . >= 8))
```

**Output**

```
       BoneMarrow Pulmonary
ATP1B1         30      3380
PRR11        2703        27
```