# How to mutate columns but keep rownames in R pipe?

Tags: r

```
r$> iris %>% .[which(as.numeric(rownames(.))%%3!=0),] %>% rownames
  [1] "1"   "2"   "4"   "5"   "7"   "8"   "10"  "11"  "13"  "14"  "16"  "17"  "19"  "20"  "22"  "23"  "25"  "26"  "28"  "29"  "31"  "32"  "34"  "35"  "37"  "38"  "40"  "41"  "43"  "44"  "46"
 [32] "47"  "49"  "50"  "52"  "53"  "55"  "56"  "58"  "59"  "61"  "62"  "64"  "65"  "67"  "68"  "70"  "71"  "73"  "74"  "76"  "77"  "79"  "80"  "82"  "83"  "85"  "86"  "88"  "89"  "91"  "92"
 [63] "94"  "95"  "97"  "98"  "100" "101" "103" "104" "106" "107" "109" "110" "112" "113" "115" "116" "118" "119" "121" "122" "124" "125" "127" "128" "130" "131" "133" "134" "136" "137" "139"
 [94] "140" "142" "143" "145" "146" "148" "149"

r$> iris %>% .[which(as.numeric(rownames(.))%%3!=0),] %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length+1) %>% rownames
  [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23"  "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"
 [32] "32"  "33"  "34"  "35"  "36"  "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "41"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "45"  "46"  "47"  "48"  "49"  "50"  "51"  "52"  "53"  "54"  "55"  "56"  "57"  "58"  "59"  "60"  "61"  "62"
 [63] "63"  "64"  "65"  "66"  "67"  "68"  "69"  "70"  "71"  "72"  "73"  "74"  "75"  "76"  "77"  "78"  "79"  "80"  "81"  "82"  "83"  "84"  "85"  "86"  "87"  "88"  "89"  "90"  "91"  "92"  "93"
 [94] "94"  "95"  "96"  "97"  "98"  "99"  "100"
```

I like `mutate()`,because it's easy to use in pipe.  As above example,you can find rownames changed after mutate.

I need to mutate columns but keep the rowname not changed,how to do it through R pipe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve base data frame rownames upon filtering in dplyr chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427444/how-to-preserve-base-data-frame-rownames-upon-filtering-in-dplyr-chain)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pipe. *`mutate`* removes the row names.

Comment: @KonradRudolph,I need solution in pipe format.

Comment: @kittygirl Yes, but as mentioned this isn’t important for either the question or a potential answer, since the presence or absence of the pipe operator has no influence on this. Beyond that, if you want to retain the row names you can’t use `mutate` etc. But I strongly recommend you stick to `mutate`, and get used to not having row names. It took me a while too, but once I got used to treating row names as yet another column, I realised that not using row names has absolutely no drawbacks, and many advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `mutate` or in general `dplyr` readjusts rownames from 1 after any operation hence, it does not maintain the original rownames.

If you need them for further manipulation store them as a column.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
   .[which(as.numeric(rownames(.))%%3!=0),] %>%
    mutate(row = rownames(.),
            Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length+1) %>%
    pull(row)

#  [1] "1"   "2"   "4"   "5"   "7"   "8"   "10"  "11"  "13"  "14"  "16"  "17"  "19"  "20"  "22"  "23"  "25"  "26" 
# [19] "28"  "29"  "31"  "32"  "34"  "35"  "37"  "38"  "40"  "41"  "43"  "44"  "46"  "47"  "49"  "50"  "52"  "53" 
# [37] "55"  "56"  "58"  "59"  "61"  "62"  "64"  "65"  "67"  "68"  "70"  "71"  "73"  "74"  "76"  "77"  "79"  "80" 
# [55] "82"  "83"  "85"  "86"  "88"  "89"  "91"  "92"  "94"  "95"  "97"  "98"  "100" "101" "103" "104" "106" "107"
# [73] "109" "110" "112" "113" "115" "116" "118" "119" "121" "122" "124" "125" "127" "128" "130" "131" "133" "134"
# [91] "136" "137" "139" "140" "142" "143" "145" "146" "148" "149"
```

Comment: Then,how to get the `iris` with origin rowname?

Comment: tibbles don't support rowname so you need to add them as separate column.

Comment: Any alternative function to `mutate`?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to process `column` and keep `rowname`.

Comment: That isn't clear actually but another alternative to the answer which I have shown is `iris %>% mutate(row = as.numeric(rownames(.))) %>% filter(row %%3 !=0) %>% pull(row)`

Answer (score 1):

```
iris %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(., 'rowname') %>% .[which(as.numeric(rownames(.))%%3!=0),] %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length+1) %>% tibble::column_to_rownames(.,'rowname')
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Having rownames goes against `dplyr`'s dataframe structure principles. See Hadley's reasoning [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#rownames).

Best workaround if you want to stick to dplyr is to first store the rownames as a column using `rownames_to_column`, do your manipulation, then reinstate the rownames using `column_to_rownames` (both functions are from the `tibble` package).

Using your example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

iris %>% 
.[which(as.numeric(rownames(.))%%3!=0),] %>% 
# store rownames in a column
rownames_to_column(var = "rowid") %>%
# dplyr manipulation
mutate(Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length+1) %>% 
# reinstate rownames
column_to_rownames(var = "rowid") %>% 
# check rownames
rownames()

# [1] "1"   "2"   "4"   "5"   "7"   "8"   "10"  "11"  "13"  "14"  "16"  "17"  "19"  "20"  "22"  "23"  "25"  "26"  "28"  "29"  "31"  "32"  "34"  "35"  "37"  "38" 
# [27] "40"  "41"  "43"  "44"  "46"  "47"  "49"  "50"  "52"  "53"  "55"  "56"  "58"  "59"  "61"  "62"  "64"  "65"  "67"  "68"  "70"  "71"  "73"  "74"  "76"  "77" 
# [53] "79"  "80"  "82"  "83"  "85"  "86"  "88"  "89"  "91"  "92"  "94"  "95"  "97"  "98"  "100" "101" "103" "104" "106" "107" "109" "110" "112" "113" "115" "116"
# [79] "118" "119" "121" "122" "124" "125" "127" "128" "130" "131" "133" "134" "136" "137" "139" "140" "142" "143" "145" "146" "148" "149"
```